# Map data between two dataframes when header of dataframe contains string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping

I want to **scrape** the CFO's salary for a list of companies from the Summary Compensation Table which is obtained from an SEC filing (DEF 14A).
Since I want to do this for a whole list of CFOs, I started by creating a dictionary that contains the surname of the CFO, the CIK of the company (ID to identify the company), and the year for which I want to scrape the salary.

In a first step I add the filings link to the dict and use `tables = soup.find_all("table")` to extract all the tables that the filing contains. Next I identify the compensation table, transfer it into a pandas dataframe using `df = pd.read_html()` and add the dataframe to the dict as well.
Unfortunately, the original tables are not really standardized, so I try to harmonize them as much as possible.

These are two examples of dataframes, after I have standardized them as best as I could:

CFO Surname in the first case is Hernandez.
[image]
CFO Surname in the second case is Johnson.
[image]

Ultimately, I have a number of more or less standardized dataframes, from which I want to extract the needed information (CFO Name, Year, Salary, Bonus) and merged them into a new single dataframe.

For this purpose I created an empty dataframe first:

```
columns = ["CFO Name", "Year", "Salary", "Bonus"]

finaldf = pd.DataFrame(columns=columns)
finaldf
```

Unfortunately, I am not able to match the desired information.
I was thinking of a string matching approach based on the headings. Even though the headings of the dataframes columns are unlikely to be identical (see example dataframes), there should always be a column whose heading contains, for example, the string "Year".

So the code should follow the following logic:

Search in the first column of each DataFrame (the first column always contains the names of the executives, at least this is somehow identical over all companies...) for the surname of the CFO. Transfer the name from the DataFrame to the "CFO Name" column of the finaldf.
Move on and check which column header contains the string "Year". Transfer the data to the "Year" column of the finaldf.
Move on and check which column header contains the string "Salary". Transfer the data into the column "Salary" of the finaldf.
Finally, move on and check which column header contains the string "Bonus". Transfer the data to the "Bonus" column of the finaldf.

EDIT: Here is a sample of a compensation table in html format

```html
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<th align="LEFT" colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="6"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Annual Compensation </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="100%"/></th>
<th colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Long-Term|Compensation|Awards </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<th align="LEFT" colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Name and Principal Position </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="75%"/></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Year </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Salary(1)|($) </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Bonus(2)|($) </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Other|($) </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="1"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></th>
<th colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">Securities|Underlying|Options|(#) </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th>
<th colspan="2"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1">All Other|Compensation|($) </font><hr noshade="" size="1" width="90%"/></th></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT" width="38%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">T.J. Rodgers</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="3%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">2000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT" width="9%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$371,060</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT" width="9%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$712,528</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT" width="8%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   1,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(3) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT" width="9%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">400,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="2%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT" width="9%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT" width="3%"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  President, Chief Executive</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1999</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$337,706</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$405,316</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   1,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(3) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">300,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Officer and Director</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1998</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$344,453</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  57,236</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   1,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(3) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">200,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="14"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">J. Daniel McCranie (4)</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">2000</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$342,990</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  97,994</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">0</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Vice President, Business</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1999</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$332,556</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$291,173</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">70,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   335,075</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(6)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Development (Retired)</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1998</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$321,054</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  57,936</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">192,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   229,165</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(5)</font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="14"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">Ralph Schmitt</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">2000</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$213,074</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$297,115</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$86,441</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(7) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">110,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$       8,473</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(10)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Vice President, Marketing and</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1999</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$179,622</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  11,632</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$89,919</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(7) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">40,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   285,787</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(9)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Sales</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1998</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$162,901</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$    1,598</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$19,530</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(7) </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">20,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$     18,702</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(8)</font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="14"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">Antonio R. Alvarez</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">2000</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$335,260</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$426,484</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">70,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$          600</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(12)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Vice President, Memory </font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1999</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$316,425</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$257,815</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">70,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$   322,108</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(11)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Products Division and Research</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1998</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$281,538</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  39,680</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">135,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  and Development</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="14"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="1"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">Emmanuel T. Hernandez</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">2000</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$307,607</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$410,852</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">40,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$          600</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(12)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Vice President, Finance and</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1999</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$273,130</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$261,437</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">80,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$2,900,255</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">(13)</font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Administration, and Chief</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">1998</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$246,192</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">$  56,485</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td><td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">233,000</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">—</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
<tr valign="BOTTOM">
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2">  Financial Officer</font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="RIGHT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td>
<td align="LEFT"><font face="Times New Roman, Times, Serif" size="2"> </font></td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the html "tables" from which you're extracting this information? You're much better off fixing the problems with the data at the source than trying to fix them after putting them into a dataframe.

Comment: Sure, I just added the html version of a compensation table to my original post. The variable "tables" is just a list of every html table. I extract the summary compensation table using keywords like "Year", "Salary" and "Bonus".

Comment: Sorry, are you able to provide the html source?

Comment: Hope I understood you right that you refer to the filing, here you go: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0000791915/000089155401501833/d70430_proxy.htm